# Get Customer group details in customer_group_save_after event

Tags: php, magento

I am using `customer_group_save_after_event`
and calling by observer method in that.
I want to get all post data in that method. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
    class Namespace_Customer_Model_Observer
    {
      public function setMinOrderPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
      {
        $data = $observer->getRequest()->getPost();
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";
        die("dede");

      }


}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
```